# Creating time index that creates same intervals every day

Tags: r, xts, posixct

I want to make a time index that starts at 9:15:00 and progress in 50-minute intervals before ending at 03:30:00. E.g. 9:15:00,10:05:00, 10:55:00 and so on. This is my code that perfectly creates these time indices for 1st day. However, it becomes messed up next day and ***begins at 09:25:00 instead of 09:15:00*** and gets all intervals wrong. The start time keeps changing every day.

```
Intervals <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 09:15:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2016-04-29 15:30:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                   by="50 min")
```

As I am trying to calculate various intervals by change only argument `by="50 min"` for example to `by="55 min"` and need flexibility in fixing the end time, so I put it as ***before 15:30:00*** . Please me to fix It?

Comment: Since when has April had 31 days? I think you have a typo.

Comment: Your intervals never hit 03:30:00 either. And why would you think it would come back around to the same start point each day? You are not progressing by an interval that divides neatly into an hour or day.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for helping me with date. I want to end this before 15:30:00 so in this case, it ends on 15:05:00. As I am trying to calculate various intervals by change only  by="50 min" for example to  by="55 min" and need flexibility in fixing the end time, so I put it as "before 15:30:00"

Comment: What if you just do the calculations for a single day (make both start and stop "2016-04-01"), then add a bunch of days on? Something like `Intervals + as.difftime(rep(0:10,each=length(Intervals)), units="days")`

Comment: @thelatemail I am a beginner in xts. So, kindly make it accessible to me?

Comment: `Intervals <- seq(
  as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 09:15:00"),
  as.POSIXct("2016-04-01 15:30:00"),
  by="50 min"
)` then `Intervals + as.difftime(rep(0:10,each=length(Intervals)), units="days")` - that should just work to give you a consistent sequence starting and ending at the same point each day.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks, it seems to work. But how do I do this for the dates I have shown. Also, consider writing an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be better off generating one sequence and reusing this for each day. As so:

```
start <- "2016-04-01"
stop  <- "2016-04-29"
daylength <- difftime(as.POSIXct(stop), as.POSIXct(start), units="days")

Intervals <- seq(
  as.POSIXct(paste(start, "09:15")),
  as.POSIXct(paste(start, "15:30")),
  by="50 min"
)

out <- Intervals + as.difftime(rep(0:daylength, each=length(Intervals)), units="days")
range(out)
#[1] "2016-04-01 09:15:00 AEST" "2016-04-29 15:05:00 AEST"
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(..., tz="insert_timezone_here")` for each part. Type `OlsonNames()` in R and hit enter to see what timezone options are available on your system.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth exploring making use of the `cut` function. For example for the set of *days:*

```
myDays <-
    seq(
        from = as.Date("2016-04-01"),
        to = as.Date("2016-04-29"),
        by = "day"
    )
```

the one could arrive at 50 minutes intervals for each day via:

```
myIntervals <-
    data.frame(table(cut(x = as.POSIXct(myDays), breaks = "50 min")))
```

### *Preview*

```
>> head(myIntervals, 10)
                  Var1 Freq
1  2016-04-01 01:00:00    1
2  2016-04-01 01:50:00    0
3  2016-04-01 02:40:00    0
4  2016-04-01 03:30:00    0
5  2016-04-01 04:20:00    0
6  2016-04-01 05:10:00    0
7  2016-04-01 06:00:00    0
8  2016-04-01 06:50:00    0
9  2016-04-01 07:40:00    0
10 2016-04-01 08:30:00    0
```